# Adding string to pandas properly

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Ive been trying to add a list of string values to another dataframe in python using pandas and it adds the whole list to the first value

```
                                                 prices    Close
0      331.462585\n 332.892242\n 328.274536\n 323.79...      NaN
0                                                   NaN   314.73
1                                                   NaN   314.95
2                                                   NaN   315.02
3                                                   NaN   315.08
...                                                 ...      ...
2396                                                NaN  2782.11
2397                                                NaN  2780.52
2398                                                NaN  2779.25
2399                                                NaN  2777.62
2400                                                NaN  2776.15
```

this is what i currently have set up

```py
sma = get_sma()
sma = pd.DataFrame(sma)
prices = pd.DataFrame(data['Close'])
prices = prices.to_string(index = False, header=False)
# prices = pd.DataFrame(prices)
prices = pd.DataFrame([prices], columns=['prices'])
frames = [prices, sma]
# print(sma)
combined = pd.concat(frames)
print(combined)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a little hard to understand from your post what each data frame contains but I can guess you should use join:

```
sma = get_sma()
sma = pd.DataFrame(sma)
prices = pd.DataFrame(data['Close'])
prices = prices.to_string(index = False, header=False)
# prices = pd.DataFrame(prices)
prices = pd.DataFrame([prices], columns=['prices'])
frames = [prices, sma]
# print(sma)
combined = prices.merge(sma,left_index=True,right_index = True)
print(combined)
```

you can read [this](https://www.statology.org/pandas-merge-on-index/) tutorial for more information